# ¿Cómo añadir elementos mediante dat.GUI utilizando JavaScript a una superficie ya graficada con ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Pues me encuentro con el problema de que, cuando intento agregar elementos a un control [dat.GUI](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui) en JavaScript tengo conflictos con el código y ésta me borra la grafica generada con [Three.js](https://threejs.org/) al incluir un elemento en la GUI:

[image: Parte de la gráfica de fondo junto con parte del código de la GUI y de la superficie graficada]

Ahora, si procedo a eliminar el comentario en la linea `gui.add(text, 'HOLA');` ocurre esto:

[image: La grafica se elimina, y nisiquiera aparece el nuevo elemento "HOLA" en la GUI]

¿Cómo podría solucionar esto? Dejo el código completo en JavaScript para que puedan verlo.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PROYECTO 1 - Daniel Ramos C.I. 26.237.178</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datos.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100000 );

        //Cambiando el color del fondo
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);

        //Escala de X
        var xnScale = 0;
        var xpScale = 6000;

        //Escala de Y
        var ynScale = 0;
        var ypScale = 3000;

        //Escala de Z
        var znScale = 0;
        var zpScale = 3000;

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        var xValues = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < datos.x.length; i++) {
            xValues.push(datos.x[i]);
        }

        //Buscando XMIN
        var xMin = Math.min.apply(null, xValues);
        //Buscando XMAX
        var xMax = Math.max.apply(null, xValues);

        xValues = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < datos.y.length; i++) {
            xValues.push(datos.y[i]);
        }

        //Buscando YMin
        var yMin = Math.min.apply(null, xValues);
        //Buscando YMax
        var yMax = Math.max.apply(null, xValues);

        xValues = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < datos.z.length; i++) {
            xValues.push(datos.z[i]);
        }

        //Buscando ZMin
        var zMin = Math.min.apply(null, xValues);
        //Buscando ZMax
        var zMax = Math.max.apply(null, xValues);

        //Divisiones de X
        var xnDiv = (xpScale - xnScale)/(xMax - xMin);
        //Divisiones de Y
        var ynDiv = (ypScale - ynScale)/(yMax - yMin);
        //Divisiones de Z
        var znDiv = (zpScale - znScale)/(zMax - zMin);

        //Calculando las X para visualización (Valores en pantalla)
        var xsValues = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < datos.x.length; i++) {
            xsValues.push(((datos.x[i] - xMin) * xnDiv + xnScale));
        }

        //Calculando las Y para visualización (Valores en pantalla)
        var ysValues = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < datos.y.length; i++) {
            ysValues.push(((datos.y[i] - yMin) * ynDiv + ynScale));
        }

        //Calculando las Z para visualización (Valores en pantalla)
        var zsValues = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < datos.z.length; i++) {
            zsValues.push(((datos.z[i] - zMin) * znDiv + znScale));
        }

        //Guardando todos los puntos
        var allPoints = new Array();

        //Juntando los puntos para modelar la figura (vertices).
        for(var i = 0, p = 0; i < zsValues.length; p++) {
            for(var h = 0; h < xsValues.length; h++, i++) {
                allPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(xsValues[p], ysValues[h], zsValues[i]));
            }
        }

        //Geometria
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

        //Vertices de la geometría
        for(var i = 0; i < allPoints.length; i++) {
            geometry.vertices.push(allPoints[i]);
        }

        /*text = {
            Funcion_1: defaults.zFunction,
            graficar: function() { createGraph() },
            estado: false,
            eliminar: function() { deleteGraph()},
            ayuda: function(){ help()},
            reiniciar: function(){ reloadGraph()}
        };*/


        gui = new dat.GUI();
        gui.add(text, 'HOLA');

        //Construyendo las caras
        for(var i = 0, p = 99; i < allPoints.length - xsValues.length; i++) {

            if(i == p) {
                p += 100;
                continue;
            }

            geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(i, i + xsValues.length, i + xsValues.length + 1));

            geometry.faces[geometry.faces.length - 1].vertexColors[0] = new THREE.Color(datos.colors[i]);
            geometry.faces[geometry.faces.length - 1].vertexColors[1] = new THREE.Color(datos.colors[i + ysValues.length]);
            geometry.faces[geometry.faces.length - 1].vertexColors[2] = new THREE.Color(datos.colors[i + ysValues.length + 1]);

            geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(i , i + 1 , i + xsValues.length + 1));

            geometry.faces[geometry.faces.length - 1].vertexColors[0] = new THREE.Color(datos.colors[i]);
            geometry.faces[geometry.faces.length - 1].vertexColors[1] = new THREE.Color(datos.colors[i + 1]);
            geometry.faces[geometry.faces.length - 1].vertexColors[2] = new THREE.Color(datos.colors[i + ysValues.length + 1]);
        }

        //Material
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ side: THREE.DoubleSide, 
                                                     vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
                                                     wireframe: false });
        //vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors

        //Mesh
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        //Añadiendo la geometría al mundo
        scene.add(mesh);


        //Dibujando los ejes (en forma de malla)

        var xgMin = Math.min.apply(null, xsValues);
        var xgMax = Math.max.apply(null, xsValues);

        var ygMin = Math.min.apply(null, ysValues);
        var ygMax = Math.max.apply(null, ysValues);

        var zgMin = Math.min.apply(null, zsValues);
        var zgMax = Math.max.apply(null, zsValues);

        var extra = 1000;
        var decrement = 650;

        //Lineas horizontales (Ejes X y Z)
        paintLine([new THREE.Vector3(xgMin - extra, ygMin - extra, zgMin - extra), new THREE.Vector3(xgMax + extra, ygMin - extra, zgMin - extra)]);

        for(var i = ygMax + extra; i > ygMin - extra; i -= decrement) {
            paintLine([new THREE.Vector3(xgMin - extra, i, zgMin - extra), new THREE.Vector3(xgMax + extra, i, zgMin - extra)]);
            //Lineas frontales - horizontales
            paintLine([new THREE.Vector3(xgMin - extra, i, zgMin - extra), new THREE.Vector3(xgMin - extra, i, zgMax + extra)]);
        }

        //Lineas verticales (Eje Y)

        paintLine([new THREE.Vector3(xgMin - extra, ygMin - extra, zgMin - extra), new THREE.Vector3(xgMin - extra,ygMax + extra, zgMin - extra)]);

        for(var i = xgMax + extra; i > xgMin - extra; i -= decrement) {
            paintLine([new THREE.Vector3(i, ygMin - extra, zgMin - extra), new THREE.Vector3(i,ygMax + extra, zgMin - extra)])
        }

        //Lineas frontales (Lineas verticales del eje Z)
        paintLine([new THREE.Vector3(xgMin - extra, ygMin - extra, zgMin - extra), new THREE.Vector3(xgMin - extra, ygMin - extra, zgMax + extra)]);

        for(var i = zgMax + extra; i > zgMin - extra; i -= decrement) {
            paintLine([new THREE.Vector3(xgMin - extra, ygMin - extra, i), new THREE.Vector3(xgMin - extra, ygMax + extra, i)]);
        }

        //Funcion que genera una linea pasando dos puntos de la misma como parametros

        function paintLine(points) {
            var curve = new THREE.SplineCurve3(points);

            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            geometry.vertices = curve.getPoints(50);

            var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color : 0x000000 });

            var lineObject = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);

            scene.add(lineObject);
        }

        //Controles
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        //Posicionando camara
        camera.position.set(1500, 1000, 3000);

        var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        render();
    </script>
</body>
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Estás intentando usar dat.GUI sobre una variable que no existe, es posible que te salte algún error por ello. Mira bien cómo funciona esa librería: http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage

Comment: Le agregué links y tags a tu pregunta para que entendamos que hablas de dat.GUI y Three.js. 

En segundo lugar, estás añadiendo un control sobre un objeto `text` que no existe y menos tiene una propiedad pública `HOLA`. Tendrías que crear el control `dat.GUI` sobre `geometry`, `mesh` o `material` por ejemplo. Finalmente, después de alterar una propiedad de esos objetos, Three.js va a necesitar que ejecutes de nuevo el render.

Por favor pon el contenido de `datos.js` para intentar reproducir el error.